# Does unique lifting of all paths imply a bijection?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

Suppose we have a map $p:E \rightarrow B$ such that all paths lift uniquely. Does this imply a bijection? Here $B,E$ are path-connected, locally path-connected

---

**Definition** *(Unique path lifting)*: For all paths $\alpha:[0,1] \rightarrow B$ and a point $e \in p^{-1}(b)$ there is a unique path $\overline{\alpha}: [0,1] \rightarrow E$ such that $\overline{\alpha}(0) = e$

---

$p$ has to be a bijection.
Proof: Assume that $p$ is not injective that is there is at least one pair of $x,y$ such that $p(x) = p(y) = d$ but $x \neq y$. The result follows from unique path lifting property.(Because if $\alpha(0) = d$ then both paths $\overline{\alpha}_1(0) = x \ \text{and} \ \overline{\alpha}_2(0) = y$ lift to $\alpha$ (where $\alpha(0) = d$) must be, by uniqueness identically equal implying $x = y$)
If $p$ is not onto there would exist a element of $B$ which is not the image of any element of $E$. This would mean
that there is a point $e$ such that it has no inverse. Which means no map lifts to $e$, but by path connectedness, there is a $\alpha_i$ such that $\alpha(0) = e$ but that contradicts **all** paths lift uniquely

---

But there is also a counterexample I ran into, if $E$ is bigger than $B$ (I terms of cardinality (number of elements)) then we get a counterexample or do we not?

---

Can someone explain what is wrong in the proof or the counterexample? Either one of them has to be true right? I think I messed up the surjective case

Comment: @PaulFrost sorry, it should be all paths lift I will edit it right away

Comment: "Uniquely" is in the title but not the body; the question turns on whether or not that's a hypothesis.

Comment: And you must properly define what "unique path lifting" means. If it is the usual interpretation, then your proof is not correct.

Comment: @PaulFrost I have added the definition

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your proof is not correct.

1. Look at $p : \mathbb R \to S^1, p(t) = e^{it}$. This is a non-bijective covering projection (and therefore has unique path lifting).
2. There are two defects in your proof of injectivity: (a) You do not specify which path $\alpha$ in $B$ you lift;  but clearly you can take the constant path at $d$. (b) The two lifts $\overline\alpha_i$ have to begin at $x$ and $y$, respectively. Thus you have two distinct lifts (each of then uniquely determined by its initial point) and certainly you do not have $x = y$.

Your proof of surjectivity has the right idea, but I think it is not properly elaborated. Do it as follows:

Fix $b_0 \in p(E)$. For each $b \in B$ there is a path $\alpha$ in $B$ from $b_0$ tp $b$. Lift $\alpha$ to a path $\overline\alpha$ in $E$ and set $e = \overline\alpha(1)$. Then $p(e) = \alpha(1) = b$. This shows $b \in p(E)$.

Comment: Thank you makes sense